# Can wildcards be used in the website whitelist/blacklist in macOS Parental Controls?

Tags: macos, parental-controls

In the Web section of Parental Controls in System Preferences in macOS, under Customize, can wildcards be used under "Always allow these websites" and "Never allow these websites"? For example, if I want to allow/deny `example.com` and all subdomains thereof, will it work if I add an entry for `*.example.com`? Or is this implicit by just adding `example.com`?

Comment: Have you tried it? I would imagine `example.com` also blocks all subdomains, but maybe not...